# Are find_by_[dynamic] Activerecord methods safe for unsanitized input?

Tags: ruby, rails-activerecord

I am using ActiveRecord and Sinatra (probably irrelevant context). ActiveRecord has a dynamic finder method `find_by_[column]`

I would like to pass a raw parameter string from HTTP directly into one of these methods. I'm *pretty sure* that ActiveRecord will sanitize the string I pass in. Right? Here's some example code to show what I want to do:

```
post '/login' do
  user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])
  ...
end
```

Is it problematic to pass unsanitized http parameters into this kind of ActiveRecord method?

More generally, how should one go about figuring out which ActiveRecord methods sanitize their inputs? I keep reading this site and getting scared! http://rails-sqli.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are safe. Because the dynamic finders are simply translated into the normal hash form. Find the implementation at [github](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/08754f12e65a9ec79633a605e986d0f1ffa4b251/activerecord/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb)

Note that the new syntax (since version 4) is: `find_by(username: params[:username])`

Answer (score 0):

To be sure if the user exists you can try something like:

```
if User.exists? :username => params[:username]
 user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])
end
```

This greatly reduces the chances of SQLi.